# Elastic Beanstalk : how to deploy only file modification without deploying all

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

With AWS Beanstalk (load balancing auto-scaling mode) I can deploy my application from a git repository. But if I want to make modifications on some files, I find no solutions ... I must deploy all again.

**My first question** is how I can upload only some modified files without deploying all again ?

**My second question** is : if I manually change the permissions of a folder directly on the EC2 server created by beanstalk, this change will be replicated to other futures instances (auto-scaling created automatically by beanstalk) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234304/how-to-handle-elastic-beanstalk-deployment-so-it-uploads-only-changed-files

Answer (score 4):

Elastic Beanstalk does not provide a way to update some files and not others. When EB does an update, it will update all the files.

You should avoid making changes directly to the EC2 instances:

1. Changes will NOT propagate to the other instances, and
2. If your instances are terminated and replaced (due to autoscaling and/or configuration changes), you will lose those changes.

If you want to make changes to the EC2 instances, the you should use the `.ebextensions` folder config files to make those changes. Please see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html for more information on that.